# How do I extract a value from page element, to use in a later step in ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm using ruby, selenium webdriver within cucumber to run my tests.

I have the following code;

```
<input class="input" value="qa-regression-test-1" id="furl" name="furl" type="text" aria-invalid="false">
```

And I need to extract the 'value' part of this code, and then use this value (qa-regression-test-1 in this particular case) to navigate the webdriver to a new URL.

i.e. http://www.xxxxx.co.uk/qa-regression-test-1

However, this 'value' will be different for each test, so this is why I need to get this 'value', and then use it for the final part of the subsequent URL rather than just use this current value.

Hope this is clear, but can provide more info if required.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Just a quick update on this. I tried the following; `friendlyurl= @driver.find_element(xpath: "//input[@id='furl']").attribute('value')`
`puts friendlyurl.text` but his resulted in an error (which I kind of expected) of 'undefined method text for 'qa-regression-test-1'. I feel as if I'm agonizingly close to this, but can't quite figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there - just `puts friendlyurl` instead of `puts friendlyurl.text`

:)

Basically you're good to go - just slam that String together with the host part of your url

Comment: Ahhh, I knew I was close! Brilliant, many thanks for your reply, it's much appreciated.